# What is the purpose of the air inlets on an A320neo's pylon (LEAP-1A)?

Tags: feature-identification, engine-design, nacelle, airbus-neo, engine-pylon

What is the purpose of the air inlets on an A320neo's pylon (LEAP-1A)? Passive cooling, air bleed [like in the 707](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/50697/14897), or something else?

[image: Air inlets A320neo pylon]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not unique to the LEAP. You can find similar grills on the [CFM56-5](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CS-TKK_A320_SATA_CFM56-5_OPO.jpg) and [Trent 700](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Swiss-International-Air-Lines/Airbus-A330-343/1899910/L), for example. That grill is the PCE's (**p**re**c**ooler heat **e**xchanger) air outlet.

Compressed (hot) air is taken from the engines (before combustion) for pressurization and air conditioning. This air has to pass through a PCE (cooled by [air from the fan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI3uv.png)) before heading to the [PACKs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_cycle_machine) at about 200°C. The PCE is typically located in the pylon due to space constraints.

> [image]
>   CFM56-5 (A320) bleed users; source: [slideplayer.com.br](https://slideplayer.com.br/slide/2321443/)

The largest of turbofans don't have the PCE inside the pylon, and instead have them in the cold bypass stream *(as shown below),* as does [the 737](https://www.k-makris.gr/gallery-6/) due to its short pylon (or almost nonexistent pylon on the -3/4/500 series).

> [image]
>   Source: Boeing via [leehamnews.com](https://leehamnews.com/2016/02/05/bjorns-corner-efficient-systems/)